# vba check if item in drop down list is selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get VBA to show a MsgBox if `Yes` is selected in a list box. The list box does not have any specific id, however this code should apply to all list boxes in my column. Can someone show em why this is not working?

I am getting an object undefined error, my first if statement works fine.

Thanks

```
If Target.Column = Range("V1").Column And _
   Range("R" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "" And _
   Range("V" & ActiveCell.Row).Value <> "Yes" And _
   Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Pending" And _
   Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value <> "" Then
    If ListBox.SelectedIndex = "Yes" Then
        MsgBox "Are You Sure you want to set-up the supplier on AX?" & vbNewLine & _
               "Waiting for Manager Approval & Documents have not been returned!"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting through the first if statement?

Comment: yes the first if statement works fine, this is not the problem

Comment: The error probably lies in the fact that you aren't specifying a defined ListBox object then. I suggest you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195480(v=office.15).aspx) to understand them better.

Answer (score 1):

```
    If ListBox.SelectedIndex = "Yes" Then
```

`SelectedIndex` returns the index, so 1 or 4 etc.

If you want to compare the actual value, use `SelectedValue` such as:

```
    If ListBox.SelectedValue= "Yes" Then
```